# Is there any way to use hashmap without using Synchronized keyword

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

Now I want to make HashMap synchronized .Is there any way I can do the same without using Synchronized keyword ConcurrentHashMap?or ? That is I dont want to put all the methods inside a Synchronized block .

Comment: Consider using ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: actual requirement is what?

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to make ArrayList and HashMap synchronized .Is there any way I can do the same without using Synchronized keyword ?

Sure:

1. Use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) and any of the several `List` implementations in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).
2. Use [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) and  [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-).

Comment: any example for it ?

Comment: @dilshad: You mean like `Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());`?

Comment: no  i mean about create own synchronized hashmap using some kind of login

Comment: @dilshad: "login"? Huh?